# Uncaught exception: unknown (can't convert to string)

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing code for the Firefox browser addon and I am trying to update the value of cookies using chrome API.
While calling the chrome.cookies.set method, it returns the following error on the console.

**Error: uncaught exception: unknown (can't convert to string)**

```
var finalCookieObj = { 
    domain: ".qa.soul.com", 
    name: "aaa", 
    value: "as", 
    path: "/", 
    httpOnly: false, 
    url: "qa.soul.com/", 
    expirationDate: 1459788960 
};

chrome.cookies.set(finalCookieObj, function(cookie) {
    console.log('added cookie');
});
```

API reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set

Comment: Please share the value of `finalCookieObj`, as it's most likely one of the fields in this object that has a problem.

Comment: Object { domain: ".qa.soul.com", name: "aaa", value: "as", path: "/", httpOnly: false, url: "http://www.qa.soul.com/page1", expirationDate: 1459788960 }

Comment: What is `chrome` in this example? I only ask because you say you're using it for a FF addon?

Comment: The following permission entry is present in the manifest.json.      "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking" , "cookies", "<all_urls>", "*"]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `url` needs to be a fully-qualified URL, including protocol. This version works:

```
var finalCookieObj = { 
    domain: ".qa.soul.com", 
    name: "aaa", 
    value: "as", 
    path: "/", 
    httpOnly: false, 
    url: "https://qa.soul.com/", 
    expirationDate: 1459788960 
};

chrome.cookies.set(finalCookieObj, function(cookie) {
    console.log('added cookie');
});
```

I'll update the docs to be explicit about this.

Also, asynchronous functions report errors by setting [chrome.runtime.lastError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Runtime/lastError): it's always a good idea to check this in your callback.

It's funny, though, I see different console output to you. I see an error like this:

```
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a 
(NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]"  nsresult:
"0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI)"  location: "JS frame
:: resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm :: NetUtil_newURI ::
line 191" data: no]
```

... that includes a call stack containing `NetUtil_newURI()`, that was enough to point to the `url` as the problem. Which console are you looking at?

Comment: Thanks @wbamberg for the reply. I have taken the Firefox nightly build version 48 and its working fine with no code changes. But Its not working in the production release version 45. Is it going to be fixed soon in the current version? I was referring to the Firefox web console.

Comment: I am still getting error after updating the url value with fully qualified URL including protocol. Please check the screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/a96g66bj73uno8d/Screenshot%202016-04-10%2017.48.59.png?dl=0

Comment: Firefox web console output:
screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tt2hgglic56kq8c/Screenshot%202016-04-10%2018.23.42.png?dl=0

Comment: did you get a chance to see the scrrenshot?